# Storing clicks count to localstorage html5

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, vs-web-site-project

Made a http://jsfiddle.net/ddvQU/30/ jsfiddle that counts the clicks in a div area.

```
 <textarea id="ta" placeholder="Type your text here..."></textarea>
 <p id="ta-log"></p>
```

I am looking to store that number of clicks so when the user navigates away from the page (Closes it) I can recall the number from localstorage.

Comment: So what did you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddvQU/31/) and it does what you want:

```
$( function() {
    var clickCount = localStorage.getItem('clickCount');
    clickCount = clickCount ? parseInt(clickCount) : 0;
    var $num = $('.num');
    $num.text(clickCount);
    $('.box').click( function() {
        $num.text(++clickCount);
        localStorage.setItem('clickCount', clickCount);
    });
});
```

I haven't used try ... catch blocks, but in real life you should, as you could get errors trying to access localStorage, because it can be disabled or you could have consumed your disk quota.

Comment: Thanks for that and I have looked into catch blocks to try and implement it into the code.

Comment: I get a NaN in the div :))